# What is the difference between *.* and * in regex?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I want to know more specifically, what is the difference between `*.*` and `*` in search pattern of winapi `FindFirstFile`?

```
GetWindowsDirectoryA( buffer2, sizeof(buffer2) );
strcat(buffer2, "\\*"); 
handle = FindFirstFileA(buffer2, &data);
```

Comment: checked this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: neither of these are *regex*

Comment: @ThunderWiring Thank you. I had studied regex before and read this page, but I can still not figure out the difference between `*` and `*.*`

Comment: FindFirstFile on MSDN does not mention regex anywhere.....  For MS API calls, MSDN should be your first stop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are not regular expressions. They are simple wildcard based search patterns.

There is in fact no difference between `*` and `*.*`. The rules for these wildcard patterns date back to DOS. Raymond Chen explains the DOS rules here: [How did wildcards work in MS-DOS?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/17/6785519.aspx) Because `*.*` was the same as `*` in DOS, this equivalence was maintained in Win32 for the sake of compatibility.

> But some quirks of the FCB matching algorithm persist into Win32 because they have become idiom.
>
> For example, if your pattern ends in `.*`, the `.*` is ignored. Without this rule, the pattern `*.*` would match only files that contained a dot, which would break probably 90% of all the batch files on the planet, as well as everybody's muscle memory, since everybody running Windows NT 3.1 grew up in a world where `*.*` meant *all files*.

Comment: ++ awesome history lesson